# React Component not found

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, reactjs.net

I'm making a React app on asp.net core. I'm using the ReactJS.NET library and webpack as my bundler and transpiler of the jsx components.

I have it working locally, but when i deplloy to azure, i get this log:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ReactEngineNotFoundException: No usable JavaScript engine was found. Please 
install a JavaScript engine such as React.JavaScriptEngine.ClearScriptV8 (on 
Windows) or React.JavaScriptEngine.VroomJs (on Linux and Mac OS X). Refer to 
the ReactJS.NET documentation for more details.
 React.AspNet.HtmlHelperExtensions.get_Environment()

TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: 
React.JavaScriptEngineFactory
 React.AspNet.HtmlHelperExtensions.get_Environment()

TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.ReactEnvironment
 React.AspNet.HtmlHelperExtensions.get_Environment()

ReactNotInitialisedException: ReactJS.NET has not been initialised correctly. 
Please ensure you have called app.AddReact() and app.UseReact() in your 
Startup.cs file.
 React.AspNet.HtmlHelperExtensions.get_Environment()
```

From ReactJS.NET Docs, "From version 2.2 onwards ReactJS.NET works out of the box in Azure using the V8 JavaScript engine". And it says ".SetAllowMsieEngine(false); on app.UseReact()", but this is now deprecated...

Not sure what to do :/ 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After alot of trying, i got it working. Found a github post https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/Registration-of-JS-engines

Installed the packages in the Core section, and added the code to the startup.cs it worked after deploying to azure. The V8 package and jurassic don't work on Core.